# php space in uploaded file replaced by underscore automatically

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

I am uploading files using php script and later displaying it through url. If uploading file contains space it get replaced with the underscore without any reason. This change of name is unwanted to me , how to stop it? I am using ubuntu operating system with PHP as programming language and codeigniter as a framework. I am doing multiupload i.e user can upload more than one file at a time. **Note :** Database entry for filename doesn't replace space with underscore.

```
    for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
        $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['docs']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['docs']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['docs']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['docs']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['docs']['size'][$i];

        $config['upload_path'] = './companies/'.$this->company_name.'/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|text|zip|doc|docx'; //Allowed file types
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')){
          $data['save_name']=$_FILES['userFile']['name'];
          if(!$this->clientdb->store($data))   // this calls storing function
             die('Error : Database connection aborted abruptly.');
        }
      }     // for loop
```

Comment: how can we answer without seeing a single line of the code you are using ?

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ If you want i can provide code. Reason to write without code was firstly i wanna check whether this is the default behaviour of linux system or php language when upload happen.

Comment: yes, you have to provide the code because the renaming is necessarily done in your code, neither linux or php will rename a file if you don't tell them to do so

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ I will paste the code in question shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It due to config change default mechanism provided by CI
Use below code

above `$this->load->library('upload', $config);`

```
    $config['remove_spaces'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Oh, thank you nishant nair. This was not expected from CI. I need to read whole documentation of CI one day. Appreciated.

Comment: @JoneDotosvky Yes me too, getting it from SO. Thanks for SO